# Which .Net-based CMS to choose for a big highload solution

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, umbraco, sitefinity, episerver

We are choosing a CMS platform for a big old solution. It's preferable to have site **on-premise**, not in cloud (company policy) and a lifelong license.

Does anyone have experience with building a solution with similar characteristics on **Umbraco / Episerver / Sitecore / Sitefinity:**

~ 4-20 mln visits a day (3 sites)

~ 4000 requests/sec

~ 6 mln pages of content (search is needed in admin for all pages)

It seems to me that headless solution would be the most suitable (with layers of caching in-between).

But is it possible to implement everything on-premise:

- scalable solution (horizontally)
- efficient search
- recommendation system

Answer (score 1):

All CMS vendors mentioned support both on-premise and cloud hosting and can easily handle such loads (if properly implemented).

Episerver has sophisticated search and recommendation engines, although those rely on cloud services even if the CMS itself is hosted on-premise.

A headless approach can be great from a technical/performance standpoint, but it does come with a risk of less user-friendly content authoring depending on the implementation.

Comment: Yes, it seems that Episerver would be a good fit if it had a possibility to support scalable on-premise search. I can see that there are some plugins that seem to support Elasticsearch for Episerver. Do you know anything about it? Is it not recommended to use?

Comment: @Ekaterina: For out-of-the-box indexing/search features, I think Episerver Find is the way to go. However, Episerver can be integrated with pretty much any search engine, and ElasticSearch is one of the more popular ones. It does require more development, however, so cost/benifit must be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use combine `Rich Content Management facilities provided by CMS` +
`Unlimited scaling options and performance`([Content Delivery Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network))

Content from [Sitecore](https://www.sitecore.com/) is published to CDN via [Uniform](https://uniform.dev/).
The result - best theoretically possible performance in any region in the world.

The specific architecture/design is to be used, though ([JAM Stack](https://jamstack.org/)).